# How to loop "pushing" to Firebase database using cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I need to add to my database a list of 3 students to 1 teacher (and assume it doesn't exist yet). Also should return dictionary to the client. I'm using cloud functions. Here is my idea, my app is frozen when I run it.

```
exports.addNewStudents = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
const totalStudent = data.total; //"3"
const teacher = data.teacher //"Robert"
var studentListToReturn = new Dictionary<string, object>(); 

for (int i=0; i<totalStudent,i++ )
{   // 'i' is going to be the student's ID and I use it in the path:
return admin.database().ref('studentsTable/teacher/'+i).push({

   date: Date();,
   class: "Highschool",
   }).then(() => {
  studentListToReturn[i]=i ;
  })

 return studentListToReturn;
```

It should look like this on my DB:

- studentsTable

  - Robert

    - 0   {date: 11/13/2018 , class:"Highschool"}
    - 1   {date: 11/13/2018 , class:"Highschool"}
    - 2   {date: 11/13/2018 , class:"Highschool"}

I'm new to cloud functions (and js) can you please help?

Comment: This is illegal syntax: `new Dictionary<string, object>();` If you're new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. You could also use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js process, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not that new... I usually program in C++/ Java, and I know js basics, it's not that different for what I need.  My question is about the loop and that specific function call to the server and the example I need. Thtat's why I didn't add the node.js tag that I see now that you added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited the code and made use of async await to make it more readable. There were a lot of JS syntax issues. I would suggest using the typescript firebase functions template and use [visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) as an editor which will give you the IntelliSense. Also you would need to add in an auth check at the top to ensure only certain people can call the function.

```
exports.addNewStudents = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    // Need to add in an auth check to make sure they have permission to do the below

    const totalStudent = data.total; //"3"
    const teacher = data.teacher //"Robert"
    const studentListToReturn: Array<any> = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < totalStudent; i++ ) {   // 'i' is going to be the student's ID and I use it in the path:
        const student: any = {
            studentId: i,
            date: Date(),
            class: "Highschool"
        }
        await admin.database().ref(`studentsTable/${teacher}/${i}`).set(student)
        studentListToReturn.push(student);
    }
    return studentListToReturn;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for auth check- is it enough to check 'context.auth!=null' ? or do I need to connect to my database and check if context.auth.uid exists theree?

Comment: It really depends if you want all authenticated users to be able to do this operation. If not then you'd want to check your database for a list of allowed user ids or something. Many ways to achieve this just about your needs